# trying to call AxInterop.ImageEnXLibrary in .net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, image-processing

*Here is the code:*

```
AxImageEnXLibrary.AxImageEnX axImageEnX = new 
AxImageEnXLibrary.AxImageEnX();
AxImageEnX.LoadFromFile(@"C:\Test.jpg");
```

*Reference Library/DLL used :*

- AxInterop.ImageEnXLibrary.dll
- Interop.ImageEnXLibrary.dll

I want to use functions of Class `AxImageEnX` but do not know how to initialize it. Come to know about GetOcx function required to be implement but its not working!

*Reference link : [Cannot run project](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?614159-RESOLVED-Cannot-run-project)*

Can anyone please help me?

Thanks.

Comment: did you have a time machine? Where did you find that ancient old library? There is like one other thread on the internet where its mentioned. What is the OCX function, is it for Optical Character Recognition? Have you tried to use P/Invoke? I'd actually recommend using a .Net component instead.